# Exceptions: re-throw and multiple catch blocks

Tags: php, exception

I have a situation where I would like to re-throw an exception inside a `catch` block and have it caught by a more generic `catch`.

Example:

```
try {
    somethingThatMightThrowExceptions();
}
catch (ClientErrorResponseException $e) {
    if ($e->getResponse()->getStatusCode() == 404) {
        return $this->notFound();
    }
    throw $e; // even tried throw new \Exception();
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    return $this->serverError('Server error');
}
```

So in my first catch block I check for a specific condition, and if that fails I would like to re-throw the exception and have it caught by the generic `catch (\Exception)` block. But in this case it just bubbles back up to the caller.

The problem is that there are actually a couple more lines of code in the final `catch`, which I don't want to repeat. I could of course extract them to a method, but that feels like overkill.

So basically I want to do it all in-line without having to add extra layers. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try throwing \Exception instead of `$e` which is 'ClientErrorResponseException` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, it makes no difference

Comment: It's due to catch only working once as you are throwing an exception not withing a `try` block. You should describe what you are trying to accomplish instead, as I am pretty sure there will be a better way to do it.

Comment: Only exceptions thrown within a `try` block are caught by the accompanying `catch` block(s). You'd need several nested `try..catch` blocks here.

Comment: All right, fair enough. @edvinas.me, could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it as such? Thanks!

Comment: I have reposted it as an answer. It's quite poor answer, but oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to catch only working once as you are throwing an exception not withing a try block. 
If you are determined, that you want to do it this way, then you need to nest `try..catch` statements as @deceze suggested in comments..

You should describe what you are trying to accomplish instead, as there might be a better way to do it.

Comment: The sample code is basically all I have in a specific method. This can't be further reduced. That's why I added "So basically I want to do it all in-line without having to add extra layers." Your answer satisfies my question perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:
a) Extract common logic to a method. (This can be overkill sometimes as you've mentioned)
b) Catch the most generic exception and check for its type. ie:

```
try{
    somethingThatMightThrowExceptions();
}
catch (\Exception $e) { // The most generic exception
    if($e instanceof ClientErrorResponseException) {
       // Some actions specific to ClientErrorResponseException
    }

    // Shared actions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

a) Catch the most generic exception and check for its type, as @deceze suggested

```
try{
    somethingThatMightThrowExceptions();
}
catch (\Exception $e) { // The most generic exception
    if($e instanceof ClientErrorResponseException) {
       // Some actions specific to ClientErrorResponseException
    }

    // Shared actions
}
```

b) Put anoter try/catch block at upper level

```
try {
    try {
        somethingThatMightThrowExceptions();
    }
    catch (ClientErrorResponseException $e) {
        // Some actions specific to ClientErrorResponseException
        throw $e ;
    }
}
catch (\Exception $e) { // The most generic exception
    // Shared actions
}
```